# How to Bring Image Inline

Tags: html, css, inline

Hello I am creating a popup box that has some text and a form on the right and a white image on the left. Unfortunately I can't seem to get the white image to be inline with the form on the right. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

http://crowdmedia.com.au/?page_id=721

HTML Code:

```
<div id="ppsPopupShell_[ID]" class="ppsPopupShell ppsPopupListsShell">
    <a href="#" class="ppsPopupClose ppsPopupClose_[close_btn]"></a>
    <div class="ppsInnerTblContent">
      <div class="ppsPopupListsInner ppsPopupInner">
          [if enb_label]
              <div class="ppsPopupLabel ppsPopupListsLabel">[label]</div>
          [endif]
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
          [if enb_txt_0]
          <div class="ppsPopupTxt ppsPopupClassyTxt ppsPopupClassyTxt_0 ppsPopupTxt_0">
              [txt_0]
          </div>
          [endif]

      </div>
      <div class="ppsRightCol">
        [if enb_txt_1]
          <div class="ppsPopupTxt ppsPopupClassyTxt ppsPopupClassyTxt_1 ppsPopupTxt_1">
              [txt_1]
          </div>
          [endif]
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        [if enb_subscribe]
        <div class="ppsSubscribeShell">
            [sub_form_start]
                [if enb_sub_name]
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                [endif]
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="[sub_btn_label]" />
            [sub_form_end]
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
        [endif]
        [if enb_sm]
        <div class="ppsSm">
          [sm_html]
        </div>
        [endif]
        [if enb_foot_note]
        <div class="ppsFootNote">
          [foot_note]
        </div>
        [endif]
      <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] {
    width: [width][width_measure];
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsInnerTblContent {
    display: block;
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsPopupInner {
  {% if popup.params.tpl.enb_subscribe or popup.params.tpl.enb_foot_note or popup.params.tpl.enb_sm %}
    width: 60%;
    box-shadow: rgba(32,32,32,1) 0 4px 20px;
    border-radius:3px;
    [else]
    width: 100%;
    [endif]
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    [if bg_type_0 == 'color']
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, {{ adjust_brightness(popup.params.tpl.bg_color_0, 50) }} 0%, [bg_color_0] 100%); /* ff3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, {{ adjust_brightness(popup.params.tpl.bg_color_0, 50) }}), color-stop(100%, [bg_color_0])); /* safari4+,chrome */
    background:-webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, {{ adjust_brightness(popup.params.tpl.bg_color_0, 50) }} 0%, [bg_color_0] 100%); /* safari5.1+,chrome10+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, {{ adjust_brightness(popup.params.tpl.bg_color_0, 50) }} 0%, [bg_color_0] 100%); /* opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, {{ adjust_brightness(popup.params.tpl.bg_color_0, 50) }} 0%, [bg_color_0] 100%); /* ie10+ */
    background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, {{ adjust_brightness(popup.params.tpl.bg_color_0, 50) }} 0%, [bg_color_0] 100%); /* w3c */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='{{ adjust_brightness(popup.params.tpl.bg_color_0, 50) }}', endColorstr='[bg_color_0]',GradientType=1 ); /* ie6-9 */
    [elseif bg_type_0 == 'img']
    background-image: url("[bg_img_0]");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    [endif]

}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsPopupLabel {
    color: #56912d;
    font-family: 'arial', arial;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #56912d;
    -moz-text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #56912d;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #56912d;

}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsRightCol {
    display: table-cell;
    border-radius:3px;
    width: 40%;
    height: 110%;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    box-shadow: rgba(32,32,32,1) 0 4px 20px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    [if bg_type_1 == 'color']
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, {{ adjust_brightness(popup.params.tpl.bg_color_1, 50) }} 0%, [bg_color_1] 100%); /* ff3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, {{ adjust_brightness(popup.params.tpl.bg_color_1, 50) }}), color-stop(100%, [bg_color_1])); /* safari4+,chrome */
    background:-webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, {{ adjust_brightness(popup.params.tpl.bg_color_1, 50) }} 0%, [bg_color_1] 100%); /* safari5.1+,chrome10+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, {{ adjust_brightness(popup.params.tpl.bg_color_1, 50) }} 0%, [bg_color_1] 100%); /* opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, {{ adjust_brightness(popup.params.tpl.bg_color_1, 50) }} 0%, [bg_color_1] 100%); /* ie10+ */
  background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, {{ adjust_brightness(popup.params.tpl.bg_color_1, 50) }} 0%, [bg_color_1] 100%); /* w3c */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='{{ adjust_brightness(popup.params.tpl.bg_color_1, 50) }}', endColorstr='[bg_color_1]',GradientType=1 ); /* ie6-9 */
    [elseif bg_type_1 == 'img']
    background-image: url("[bg_img_1]");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    [endif]

}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsSubscribeShell form {
    padding: 30px 30px 0;
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsSubscribeShell input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #d1b36d;
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsSubscribeShell input[type=text] {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #dcdcdc inset;
    padding-left: 22px;
    font-size: 17px;
    background-image: url("http://crowdmedia.com.au/wp-content/plugins/popup-by-supsystic/modules/popup/img/assets/user-black-icon.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 5px center;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsSubscribeShell input[type=text][name="email"] {
    background-image: url("http://crowdmedia.com.au/wp-content/plugins/popup-by-supsystic/modules/popup/img/assets/email-black-icon.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 5px center;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsSubscribeShell input[type=submit] {
    [if bg_type_2 == 'color']
    background: [bg_color_2];

    [elseif bg_type_2 == 'img']
    background-image: url("[bg_img_2]");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    [endif]

    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsSubscribeShell input[type=submit]:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #666;
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsPopupTxt_0 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    color: #888888;
    font-family: 'arial', arial;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsPopupTxt_1 {
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family: 'arial', arial;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 1px;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.4;
    [if enb_txt_0]
    width: 95;
    [else]
    width: 95%;
    [endif]
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsPopupClose {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    top:-20px;
    right:1px;
    z-index:99999;
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsPopupClose.ppsPopupClose_lists_black {
    top: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsPopupClose:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] .ppsFootNote{
    color: #585858;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 5px 30px;
}

#ppsPopupShell_[ID] p{
margin-left:20px;
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] b{
color: #000;
}
#ppsPopupShell_[ID] ul li {
height:30px;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you explain "get the white image to be inline with the form" this a little further? I don't get it. maybe even post a picture of how the result should look like

Comment: Basically I just want the white image to be the same height as the image with the form. Does that make sense. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

From inspecting element of the page you have regarded. You have to add the following to `#ppsPopupShell_100_14394`

```
background-color: #fff;
```

Then `#ppsPopupShell_100_14394 .ppsPopupInner` you have to remove `box-shadow`

The following is a screen shot of what I have got:

[image]

Comment: To clarify this, note that when viewing the element, it brings up a different number after `#ppsPopupShell` each time.  so basically do the same thing in your style sheet as stated but leave the numbers off and it should work.